# Comparing two file content in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, delta-lake

I have two avro files in S3 and I wish to compare the differences in the content. Basically these files would have delta differences which I want to know for further analysis. Is there any s3 native options or any AWS services that would allow me to do so?

I tried using AWS glue to generate the Data Catalog for both and compare them. But do we have any easier way to do it? Something that s3 would natively support or maybe some other AWS service that would handle it efficiently?

Comment: I have mentioned in the first line. They are .avro file.

Comment: How many rows are in the files? What would you want the output of the comparison process to be?

Comment: It is a heavy file with approximately around a million records. Everyday I will have such files coming in and I just want to see what changed between today’s data and yesterday’s data. The output can be just the records that changed with say what changed, possibly in json format.

Comment: Showing just the rows that mismatch could be done with `EXCEPT`. Showing _what_ changed will require more complex logic. If you want output in JSON, then you'll need some programming logic outside of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no standard capability for comparing files.

If you add them to the **AWS Glue Catalog**, you could use **Amazon Athena** to run SQL queries against them.

For example, if there is a primary key then you could select rows in one 'table' that are not in the other 'table', or possibly just use `EXCEPT` to look for differences between whole rows.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion. I am using AWS Glue and Athena already which is also what you suggested. What about AWS Delta lake. I heard there is something called time travel which records the differences between the versions (or files). There is not much documentation around it. It would be great if you can suggest me something there. All I want is an efficient way to find differences between two .avro file.

Comment: Delta is an alternate storage format, instead of Parquet, ORC, etc. It keeps track of changes within a table, but can't be used to compare two different files.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the clarity.